# My clickgui don't work... When i click on it

Tags: java, minecraft

So, i coding a minecraft client from quickdaffy tutorial (click gui is in 7ep)..
Another So, if i click on "testMod" button, nothing happends

Link for this tutorial: [www.youtube.com/watch?v=SR_NAVTTD5o&t](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SR_NAVTTD5o&t)

This is the code for click gui (without imports):

```
package moonlight.ui.clickgui;

public class ClickGUI extends GuiScreen {
    
    ArrayList<ModButton> modButtons = new ArrayList();
    
    @Override
    public void initGui() {
        super.initGui();
        this.modButtons.add(new ModButton(210, 60, 240, 100, Moonlight.INSTANCE.hudManager.testMod));
    }
    
    @Override
    public void drawScreen(int mouseX, int mouseY, float partialTicks) {
        ScaledResolution sr = new ScaledResolution(mc);
        super.drawScreen(mouseX, mouseY, partialTicks);
        
        Gui.drawRect(200, 50, sr.getScaledWidth(), sr.getScaledHeight(), 0x20000000);
    
        for(ModButton m : modButtons) {
            m.draw();
        }
    }
    
    @Override
    protected void mouseClicked(int mouseX, int mouseY, int mouseButton) throws IOException {
        super.mouseClicked(mouseX, mouseY, mouseButton);
    }
}
```

And this is for gui button (without imports):

```
package moonlight.ui.clickgui.comp;

public class ModButton {
    
    public int x, y, w, h;
    public HudMod m;
    
    public ModButton(int x, int y, int w, int h, HudMod m) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.w = w;
        this.h = h;
        this.m = m;
    }
    
    public void draw() {
        Gui.drawRect(y, x, h, w, 0x20000000);
        Minecraft.getMinecraft().fontRendererObj.drawString(m.name, x + 2, y + 2, getColor());
    }
    
    private int getColor() {
        if(m.isEnabled()) {
            return new Color(0,255,0,255).getRGB();
        } else {
            return new Color(255,0,0,255).getRGB();
        }

    }
    
    public void ocClick(int mouseX, int mouseY, int button) {
        if (mouseX >= x && mouseX <= x + w && mouseY >= y && mouseY <= y + h) {
            m.toggle();
            System.out.println("HELLO");
        }
    }
    
}
```

Rly, please help

Comment: Typo! `onClick` not `ocClick` in Class `ModButton`

Comment: @QuinncyJones Gosh, rly? Im stupid, thanks!

Comment: @QuinncyJones Ohh, no it still doesn't work

Comment: Is there any stacktrace or server logs when this is run? That information might make it a lot easier to resolve

Comment: @saywhatnow i'm resolved it

Comment: @katekyy Awesome! You should explain how you resolved it (as an answer) so if anyone else is in your situation, they can follow your answer